# Oracle Database 19c ucp.jar limitations with JDK 11

Tags: java, oracle, java-11, oracle19c, ojdbc

we are using database **Oracle 19c** version in production and we are migrating to JDK 11 (currently we are on JDK 7). So i downloaded necessary ojdbc jars from oracle website:
https://www.oracle.com/in/database/technologies/appdev/jdbc-downloads.html

But i found below in the website:
[image]

It said **ucp.jar certified with JDK11 but with some limitations**. Can't find any information about those limitations.

Please share if anyone has idea on those limitations.

*Please note that i'm aware Oracle 21c drivers listed in the website certified with JDK11 (including ucp.jar) but those don't have Long Term Support yet. So want to use Oracle 19c drivers only.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 19c UCP limitations with respect to JDK11 are related to the DataSource APIs added in DataSource APIs in JDK9 (for example [createConnectionBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/javax/sql/DataSource.html#createConnectionBuilder()) and [createShardingKey](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/javax/sql/CommonDataSource.html#createShardingKeyBuilder())) that you won't find in UCP in 19c. If you don't use these features, you should be fine.

And yes you're right, the current Long Term Support (LTS) release is 19c. 21c should only be used to explore new features.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Waited just to see if i get any other answers. Seems no one knows better than you .. accepted the answer..  :)